# tmux bind % and " within tmux.conf

Tags: config, tmux, color-scheme

I try to map the `%` and `"` key to a new command without success.
What I tried so far are these options:

```
bind \%      split-window -h
```

and

```
bind %      split-window -h
```

which results in an error for `\%` with `.tmux.conf:143: unknown key: \%`

both are not working.

The reason I want to remap:
I want to highlight the active pane background.
I already did it for switching pane with these options, but in splitting the color obviously is not updated.

example for switching panes:

```
bind h     select-pane  -P 'bg=default' \; select-pane -L \; select-pane  -P 'bg=black'
bind j     select-pane  -P 'bg=default' \; select-pane -D \; select-pane  -P 'bg=black'
bind k     select-pane  -P 'bg=default' \; select-pane -U \; select-pane  -P 'bg=black'
bind l     select-pane  -P 'bg=default' \; select-pane -R \; select-pane  -P 'bg=black'
```

BTW: i have tmux version 2.6

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a problem with your 2nd line, and for `"` you need to quote it. Eg this works for me in 2.6:

```
bind-key '"' split-window  \; send-keys "pwd" Enter
bind-key % split-window -h \; send-keys "pwd" Enter
```